# Convert.DateTime throws error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for "06-13-2012"

Tags: c#, datetime

I am inserting a date into my database, the value which comes from:

```
s.theDate = Convert.ToDateTime("06-13-2012");
```

and I get the error, "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". How do I resolve this?

Comment: Didn't notice that yesterday it inserted December dates?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06-13-2012", "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s.theDate = DateTime.ParseExact("06-13-2012", "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the behaviour of `ToString` on a `DateTime` type using an `InvariantCulture`, this:

```
new DateTime(2012, 6, 13).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

results in:

```
06/13/2012 00:00:00
```

So, conversely, one can assume that parsing the date with an invariant culture works Ok:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("06-13-2012", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

... and it does.

That being said, *assuming* date/time formats is a little dangerous.  I'd say you want formats to be culture-specific when the UI is considered.  Otherwise, you would want formats to be culture-agnostic.  Although Microsoft have adopted MM/dd/yyyy as a culture-agnostic format, it's an ambiguous format which isn't something that I would want to build a large system on.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ParseExact` as already suggested or populate `Convert.ToDateTime` with the second parameter:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("06-13-2012", new DateTimeFormatInfo{FullDateTimePattern = "MM-dd-yyyy"});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a global standard called ISO 8601 that you may (imo should) use. Using this standard, this is what you will end up with.

```
Convert.ToDateTime("2012-06-03");
```