# Issue in Converting Date Time c#

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I am facing an issue when converting the datetime

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
txtdate.Text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

//I need to pass it later to as a DateTime variable. When i re-convert it gives me an error)

```
DateTime dtReconvert =Convert.toDateTime(txtdate.Text);  //Error String was not recognized as a valid DateTim
```

When i set the datetime to something like "01/01/2013"
and convert it to Date Time it not giving me any error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009655/convert-datetime-throws-error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-for

Comment: I'm just curious! why not use a DateTime object throughout the code instead of converting DT to string back and forth?  What is the need for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) with the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

```
DateTime dtObject = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text, 
                                        "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: why is so can you elaborate when converting a date like "01/01/2012" it works perfectly and when you do like "23/01/2012" gives me issue what i told. Else Thanks

Comment: @user1884709, probably because your current culture supports `MM/dd/yyyy"` style date, since `01/01/2012` can be 1st Jan 2012, it is parsed. Later you are converting your date to string using a custom format, which is different from your current culture, that is why you can't parse it back to date time object. You have to use the Custom format

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtdate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Microsoft have adopted MM/dd/yyyy as a culture-agnostic format, it's an ambiguous format which isn't something that I would want to build a large system on.